# Polyglot Persistence and Data Redundancy

Tags: database-design, storage, graph, neo4j, multiple-database

I am building a project that will have a recommendation model I built with TensorFlow.

I am using MongoDB as my main database but I read about graph databases like neo4j and some people say that it can help with applications that have recommendations and can be used for real-time recommendations.

I understand that graph databases can represent relationships really well and that traversing such databases is very fast.

My concern is data redundancy, because I will have information stored in my document database but I still need some of the same information to be stored in the graph database to take advantage of its features and use it with my recommendation model.

I am new to graph databases and I'm not sure if this is a normal thing to do or if it might be a bad practice.

How do big companies usually solve this problem?

Comment: None of the mainstream databases are particularly faster than others for most use cases. "*I understand that graph databases can represent relationships really well and that traversing such databases is very fast.*" - Remove the word graph, and that sentence is still true. It's obviously easier to use 1 database system than multiple when possible, so you might want to reconsider if you can accomplish your goals with a single database system.